# C# issue with the custom Panels inside the FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, custom-controls, overriding, panel, flowlayoutpanel

**Please let me know if you need more details.**

I'm creating a thumbnail view for media (images, videos, folders) sorta like the windows view for files.

I'm using a **FlowLayoutPanel** to hold the thumbnails. And a **Panel**, **PictureBox** and **Label** for each thumbnail.

I wanted to be able to change the color/format of the border. I overrided the Panel's OnPaint and added some code in there.

Now here's the problem. The **OnPaint override** doesn't get called. Not even once. So my colored border doesn't show up at all. If I drag one onto the form it renders fine, the override gets called... So it must be something to do with the FlowLayoutPanel.

**The custom panel:**

```
public class MediaPanel : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
    public MediaPanel()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint
            | ControlStyles.UserPaint
            | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer
            | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, 
            Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing any information or I'm not explaining my problem clearly enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, I've been thinking... Maybe I should just use a **User Control** instead of the custom Panel. I'll give it a try to see if it works.

Comment: Cool, it seems to be working via **User Control**. Great, I guess I'll just put it all into this instead. I got the User Control code for colored borders from http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/523859-changing-border-color.

Comment: Works fine in an FLP, no obvious reason it shouldn't.  Technically you ought to override OnPaintBackground instead.  Beware that you'll have a *lot* of controls when you show a couple of dozen thumbnails, that's going to get seriously slow.  A ListView can do a much better job, supports custom painting too.